# SQL Server Native Client API examples

Tags: c++, sql

I am writing a C++ application that needs to execute SQL queries in a SQL Server DB and I want to do it using SQL Server Native Client.

The MSDN documentation has no a full reference on it and has a few examples so I am looking for some site having more information on how to connect, execute queries and retrieve results using this API.

Do you guys know where can I more info on it?

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to ODBC as Brian mentions, you can also use OLE DB and/or ADO (which actually makes OLE DB "easy" to use).  The three options are [`briefly introduced in this blog entry`](https://web.archive.org/web/20151004123812/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlnativeclient/archive/2006/09/27/774287.aspx).

Of the ODBC, OLE DB and ADO options, I think the simplest route would be to use ADO.  Using ODBC or OLE DB directly is, in my opinion, a somewhat painful process.  It can certainly result in very fast code, but you pay for it in development time.  [`This page`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-ado-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16) has some simple examples.

**Edit** Since this post was made (both question and answers), OLE DB has been deprecated by Microsoft.  So going forward, it probably makes sense to use a solution that does not go through OLE DB.  [This blog post](https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dang/archive/2011/09/04/rip-ole-db.aspx/) talks about it some.

Comment: The problem is that using ADO through Native Client limits you to a subset of the features available in recent SQL Server releases.  If you want support for these features, you'll want to use ODBC or OLE DB.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the [ODBC API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714562%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You can find many tutorials on Google by typing:

> ODBC API reference.